# How can I disable the inlining of subdirectories if they are empty in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

One of the new features in VSC is the grouping of subdirectories in the "explorer". Nowadays instead of ...

```
someDirectory
    anotherDirectory
        fileA
        fileB
        ...
```

... you get ...

```
someDirectory / anotherDirectory
    fileA
    fileB
    ...
```

... which I personally find not to be very convenient. My question is: How can I disable this new behavior and return to the old one? I couldn't find reasonable info about this using Google. Does anyone know how to reconfigure VSC?